# String Output Inconsistency in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm still learning in c programming, but I found an inconsistency in the output of my code. I usually use VS Code for programming. I'm playing around with string output, I'm trying to output a string containing random characters. On my VS Code laptop, the output is "100 qwerty". However, when my friend tried the code on his laptop's VS Code, the output was "100% qwerty".

```
int main () 
{
    char ss[]="100 % qwerty";
    printf(ss);
    return 0;
}
```

My friend has sent his C file to my laptop, but on my laptop the output is still "100 qwerty". Is this a wrong setting in my VS Code or is this an inconsistency in the C language or maybe is there really a problem with my code?
Thank you

Comment: Quick fix: `printf("%s\n", ss)` Now please take some time to think about what that fix does, and why it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried your suggestion and it worked. But do you know why there is a difference in output between me and my friend? That's what makes me confused. Is it true that my code is wrong? Thank you

Comment: Also please note that Visual Studio Code is just an *editor*, and it doesn't come with a compiler. Different systems could have different compilers, which could lead to different behavior for bad code.

Comment: "Why different results?" -- Because it's UB: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9. You **really really REALLY** want to avoid UB in your code. Your compiler, when set to maximum warnings, can warn you of many usual UB constructs.

Comment: I also tried my friend's file in Dev C++, but the result was the same,"100 qwerty"

Comment: @Alvin_tage be aware that "undefined bahaviour" includes "working as I expect even if the expectations are wrong".

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `100 % qwerty` as a format string to `printf`.
You should be using `puts` instead to not have characters like `%` be interpreted as format characters (esp. if `ss` ends up user-controlled; then you would be having a format string vulnerability). I assume your libc's treat `%`  differently; one treats this as an escaped space, whereas the other treats this as a literal percent sign followed by a literal space. As far as the C specification is concerned, such an invalid format specifier invokes undefined behavior, so both are valid.

Alternatively, you could use `printf("%s", ss);` to print `ss` verbatim (note: `%s\n` is slightly different in that it adds a trailing newline; you may or may not want that).

Comment: It's worth mentionning that `%` can be used in a `printf` format string by writing `%%`. So with `char ss[]="100 %% qwerty";` the OP's code would be correct.